# Calabash - ios : how to test a drag and drop action

Tags: calabash-ios

I want to test an ios app in which I have to drag and drop a button. The button is located in a UIView and I have to drop it from there to another UIView. Actually the UIView which contains the button is contained to the other UIView in which I want to drop the button. I tried to use swipe and pan but none of them was working in my case. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of [drag and drop](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/features/step_definitions/drag_and_drop_steps.rb#L72) using `pan(from_query, to_query)`.

The alternative is to pan between points.  Follow the example [in the documentation](http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/Calabash/Cucumber/Core.html#pan_coordinates-instance_method).